# "чу" і "чю" вимовляються по різному, чи однаково?

Tags: фонетика

Наскільки я розібрався, наступні пари звуків вимовляються по різному, тобто один звук в парі відрізняється від іншого.

- ЧИ ЧІ;
- ЩИ ЩІ.

Не впевнений щодо наступних пар звуків:

- ЧУ ЧЮ;
- ЧА ЧЯ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [ЯК ТРЕБА ВИМОВЛЯТИ ШИПЛЯЧІ ЗВУКИ? (*А. М. ЗАЛЕСЬКИЙ*)](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine8-7.pdf)
>
> Певні хитання в сучасній мовній практиці щодо вимови шиплячих
> спостерігаються у випадках, коли на морфемному стикові кореня й
> закінчення відбулось подовження шиплячих **ж**, **ч**, **ш** (пор.
> іменники середнього роду типу *роздоріжжя*, *піддашшя*, *клоччя*,
> *збіжжя*, *Запоріжжя*, *суччя*, *підніжжя*, а також форми орудного відмінка однини іменників жіночого роду третьої відміни з основою на
> шиплячий приголосний, напр.: *поміччю*, *річчю*, *розкішшю* та ін.).
>
> До цієї групи слів належать і кілька іменників, у яких кінцевий
> шиплячий основи стоїть після іншого приголосного і тому вже,
> зрозуміло, не може подовжуватись, але за аналогією до названих
> іменників пом’якшується перед голосними заднього ряду **а** та **у**:
> *Заволжя*, *харчю*, *жовчю*, *нехворощю*.
>
> Сучасна мовна практика засвідчує досить широку шкалу хитань і вагань у
> вимові шиплячих у цій категорії слів — від виразного ствердіння до
> напівм’якості і навіть повного пом’якшення: *зб’і́ж:а*, *п’ід:а́ш:а*,
> *пал’і́ч:а*; *зб’і́ж’іа*, *п’ід:а́ш’:а*, *пал’і́ч’:а*; *зб’і́ж':а*, *п’ід:аш':а*, *пал’іч':а*.
>
> Нам видаються передчасними рекомендації вимовляти подовжені шиплячі в
> словах *Запоріжжя*, *збіжжя*, *клоччя*, *підпіччя*, *піддашшя* тільки
> твердо.
>
> Можна припускати, що тверда вимова шиплячих у словах *зб’і́ж:а*,
> *п’ід:а́ш:а* і под. властива різним місцевим варіантам літературної мови й зумовлена впливом говіркового оточення. Таку вимову порівняно
> часто доводиться чути в носіїв літературної мови, що походять з
> Поділля.
>
> Орфоепічна традиція, яка в цьому випадку підтримується також
> орфографією (написанням після шиплячих графем я та ю, що вказують на
> пом’якшення попередніх приголосних), рекомендує у всіх словах із
> подовженими шиплячими, а також у словах *Заволжя*, *харчю*,
> *нехворощю*, *жовчю* та ін. зберігати пом’якшену вимову шиплячих.
>
> […]
>
> Отже, за орфоепічними нормами сучасної української літературної мови
> шиплячі можуть пом’якшуватися лише перед **і** (причому в такій
> позиції шиплячі завжди напівм’які) та в обмеженій кількості слів і
> словоформ перед **а** і **у** здебільшого тоді, коли шиплячі є
> подовженими (*обли́ч’:а*, *пйатир’і́ч’:а*, *н’і́ч’:у* та ін.), у всіх
> інших випадках приголосні **ж**, **ч**, **ш**, **д͡ж** слід вимовляти
> твердо.

**Коротко:** вимова за ортоепічними нормами, з підтримкою ортоґрафічних — **по-різному**; однак добра частина говірок — насамперед подільські — не розрізняють.

Гісторичні і сучасні причини я наумисно пропустив, бо це вже справа гиншого запитання, хоча певні відповідї вже єʼ в згаданій статтї — треба перейти за ланкою.

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Ще залишається питання: якщо ЧЮ за нормами пом'якшене, чи пом'якшене воно настільки, наскільки пом'якшене російське ЧУ, або все ж таки українське ЧЮ має бути за нормою меньш пом'якшене за російське ЧУ?

Comment: @AndrejAdamenko останнїй абзац цитати: _причому в такій позиції шиплячі завжди напівм’які_. Якщо порівнювати з московською, то воно _меньш пом'якшене за російське ЧУ_, котре є повністю окремим звуком і мяким.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>(Це лише моя спроба викласти [чудову відповідь Sútnôstj](/a/7418) простіше, донісши її до ширшої аудиторії. Додаткової інформації тут нема. Можливо, спроба дурна і її слід прибрати, не знаю.)</sub>

На відміну від російської, в українській мові (принаймні в стандартній українській мові) немає автоматичного м'якшення звуку *ч*. У нас *чя* — це *чя*, а *ча* — це *ча*; *чю* — це *чю*, а *чу* — це *чу*.

При цьому *чя* і *чю* вживають дуже обмежено (лише в подвоєннях, як-от *обличчя*, й окремих винятках); *ча* і *чу* — набагато частіше.

Але в діалектах є певні хитання: як в один бік (коли *чя* і *чю* твердіють, наприклад *обличчя* вимовляють майже як *обличча*), так і в інший (коли *ча* і *чу* м'якшають — або завжди, або в окремих словах/випадках — наприклад *курча* вимовляють майже як *курчя*).

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Ще залишається питання: якщо ЧЮ за нормами пом'якшене, чи пом'якшене воно настільки, наскільки пом'якшене російське ЧУ, або все ж таки українське ЧЮ має бути за нормою меньш пом'якшене за російське ЧУ?

Comment: @AndrejAdamenko, якщо чесно, я не знаю. В укр. фонетиці вважається, що в дійсно _м'якими_ можуть бути лише приголосні [д], [т], [з], [c], [ц], [д͡з], [л], [н], [р], а решта приголосних (зокрема й [ш] та [ч]) можуть бути лише _пом'якшеними_ (_напівпом'якшеними_ в інших джерелах); а в рос. фонетиці [ч] вважається м'якою, а (напів)пом'якшених взагалі не мають. Але не факт, що ця різниця між теоріями укр. і рос. мов означає, що навіть перед -ю- укр. -ч- твердіше за рос. -ч-; я не виключаю, що це може бути просто різниця в теоретичних підходах.

Answer (score -1):

Тут залежить від контексту.

В літературному стандарті Ч тверде, тому різниця є.

В частині діялектів і говорів Ч м'яке і відбувається те що ви помітили,
що чу і чю для людей звучить однаково.
Се є спадок давньоруської мови. там ч теж було м'яке і часто в різних джерелах замість  ѥ, ѧ, ю після ч писали також є, а, у. Наприклад, чѧдо—чадо [t͡ɕadɔ], чюдити—чудити [t͡ɕudɪtɪ]

особисто я цілий рік у школі вчився писати слова типу щястя-щастя,
бо там де я зростав ч саме м'яка. (покутсько-буковинська група діалектів)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).